# Firstore not returning the right order of a list

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page that displays messages with real time data from firestore. I am ordering data using a timestamp, first time I use the app(fresh install, no login) the data comes in wrong order, after that I re open the page or even the app and the data is recieved in the expected order.

I already created the index using the link shown in the Android Studio console.

In the iOS version using swift the same is happenig.

Got zero erros on console.

Here's is the functions that fetches the data from firestore (the functions is being called in the onCreate of the activity):

```
fun getInboxMessages(inboxId: String) {
    Firebase.firestore.collection("Messages")
        .whereEqualTo("inboxId", inboxId)
        .orderBy("Date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w("Firebase", "listen:error", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            for (document in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                when (document.type) {

                    DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {

                        Log.d("OrderMessages", document.document.data["Message"].toString())

                        dataInbox.add(InboxMessageModel(document.document.data["Message"].toString(), document.document.data["senderId"].toString(), document.document.data["receiverId"].toString(), calcHours(document.document.data["Date"] as Timestamp), calcMonthDay(document.document.data["Date"] as Timestamp)))
                        val chatLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                        chatLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
                        chatRecycler.layoutManager = chatLayoutManager
                        val adapterInbox = InboxAdapter(dataInbox)
                        chatRecycler.adapter = adapterInbox

                        if (document.document.data["receiverId"] as String == Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid  && document.document.data["Unread"] as Boolean == true) {
                           updateUnread(document.document.id)
                        }
                    }
                    DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {


                    /*    dataInbox.add(InboxMessageModel(document.document.data["Message"].toString(), document.document.data["senderId"].toString(), document.document.data["receiverId"].toString(), calcHours(document.document.data["Date"] as Timestamp), calcMonthDay(document.document.data["Date"] as Timestamp)))
                        val chatLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                        chatLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
                        chatRecycler.layoutManager = chatLayoutManager
                        val adapterInbox = InboxAdapter(dataInbox)
                        chatRecycler.adapter = adapterInbox */
                    }
                    DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> Log.d(
                        "Firebase",
                        "Removed Item: ${document.document.data}"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Code Edit:
So i edited the code to convert the timestamp of the field Date and then print it out on the console this is the new code:

```
fun getInboxMessages(inboxId: String) {
    Firebase.firestore.collection("Messages")
        .whereEqualTo("inboxId", inboxId)
        .orderBy("Date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w("Firebase", "listen:error", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            for (document in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                when (document.type) {
                    DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                        val timestamp = document.document.data["Date"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val milliseconds = timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
                        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMM.dd HH:mm:ss")
                        val netDate = Date(milliseconds)
                        val date = sdf.format(netDate).toString()

                        Log.d("Date From Firestore", date)
                    }
                    DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {

                    }
                    DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> Log.d(
                        "Firebase",
                        "Removed Item: ${document.document.data}"
                    )
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWaQP.png)

On fresh install of the app got the following output:

```
09:46:45.278  D  2023.January.19 01:47:34
09:46:45.280  D  2023.January.23 19:38:59
09:46:45.281  D  2023.January.23 19:39:26
09:46:45.282  D  2023.January.23 19:47:49
09:46:45.287  D  2023.January.23 19:55:49
09:46:45.291  D  2023.January.23 20:02:29
09:46:45.296  D  2023.January.23 20:03:04
09:46:45.300  D  2023.January.23 20:04:17
09:46:45.301  D  2023.January.23 20:10:48
09:46:45.302  D  2023.January.23 23:11:47
09:46:45.303  D  2023.January.23 23:16:48
09:46:45.304  D  2023.January.23 23:28:02
09:46:45.305  D  2023.January.24 00:39:23
09:46:45.311  D  2023.January.24 00:42:41
09:46:45.312  D  2023.January.24 00:44:08
09:46:45.315  D  2023.January.24 00:51:07
09:46:45.319  D  2023.January.24 00:53:10
09:46:45.336  D  2023.January.24 00:54:38
09:46:45.353  D  2023.January.24 00:56:56
09:46:45.356  D  2023.January.24 01:01:04
09:46:45.359  D  2023.January.24 01:04:54
09:46:45.367  D  2023.January.24 01:09:38
09:46:45.369  D  2023.January.24 01:11:18
09:46:45.376  D  2023.January.24 01:13:27
09:46:45.386  D  2023.January.24 01:19:44
09:46:45.389  D  2023.January.24 01:22:53
09:46:45.393  D  2023.January.24 01:23:18
09:46:45.397  D  2023.January.24 01:23:24
09:46:45.400  D  2023.January.24 01:28:55
09:46:45.404  D  2023.January.24 15:36:40
09:46:45.407  D  2023.January.24 15:39:37
09:46:45.462  D  2023.January.24 16:18:55
09:46:45.466  D  2023.January.24 16:20:22
09:46:45.474  D  2023.January.24 16:22:10
09:46:45.477  D  2023.January.24 16:56:45
09:46:45.481  D  2023.January.24 17:00:32
09:46:45.503  D  2023.January.24 17:03:37
09:46:45.506  D  2023.January.24 17:15:54
09:46:45.517  D  2023.January.24 17:16:01
09:46:45.522  D  2023.January.24 17:16:06
09:46:45.530  D  2023.January.24 17:19:28
09:46:45.543  D  2023.January.24 17:19:33
09:46:45.545  D  2023.January.24 17:26:45
09:46:45.559  D  2023.January.24 17:29:41
09:46:45.566  D  2023.January.24 19:12:07
09:46:45.586  D  2023.January.24 19:12:15
09:46:45.615  D  2023.January.24 19:20:52
09:46:45.646  D  2023.January.24 19:20:58
09:46:45.656  D  2023.January.24 19:30:58
09:46:45.657  I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 78612(3220KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(248KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 14.075ms,1.389ms total 1.083s
09:46:45.666  D  2023.January.24 19:30:58
09:46:45.689  D  2023.January.24 19:31:02
09:46:45.692  D  2023.January.24 19:31:05
09:46:45.696  D  2023.January.24 19:41:30
09:46:45.699  D  2023.January.24 20:05:07
09:46:45.701  D  2023.January.24 23:51:42
09:46:45.744  D  app_time_stats: avg=310.64ms min=37.59ms max=873.12ms count=4
09:46:46.460  V  Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
09:46:46.621  I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 87885(3861KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(104KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7634KB/14MB, paused 10.863ms,168us total 454.025ms
09:46:47.486  D  2023.January.18 16:51:53
09:46:47.486  D  2023.January.18 16:52:38
09:46:47.487  D  2023.January.18 17:03:41
09:46:47.488  D  2023.January.18 17:08:07
09:46:47.490  D  2023.January.18 17:08:31
09:46:47.498  D  2023.January.18 23:33:05
09:46:47.500  D  2023.January.18 23:36:35
09:46:47.505  D  2023.January.18 23:42:05
09:46:47.513  D  2023.January.18 23:50:51
09:46:47.519  D  2023.January.18 23:56:25
09:46:47.520  D  2023.January.19 00:04:04
09:46:47.522  D  2023.January.19 00:09:42
09:46:47.524  D  2023.January.19 00:12:10
09:46:47.530  D  2023.January.19 00:14:51
09:46:47.548  D  2023.January.19 00:18:51
09:46:47.557  D  2023.January.19 00:19:03
09:46:47.561  D  2023.January.19 00:20:57
09:46:47.598  D  2023.January.19 00:21:04
09:46:47.605  D  2023.January.19 01:33:20
09:46:47.613  D  2023.January.19 01:35:32
09:46:47.618  D  2023.January.19 01:39:22
09:46:47.622  D  2023.January.19 01:44:22
09:46:47.625  D  2023.January.19 01:44:44
09:46:47.629  D  2023.January.19 01:44:51
09:46:47.638  D  2023.January.19 01:47:24
09:46:47.639  D  2023.January.19 01:47:57
09:46:47.646  D  2023.January.19 03:13:15
09:46:47.655  D  2023.January.19 03:22:25
09:46:47.657  D  2023.January.19 09:54:43
09:46:47.658  D  2023.January.19 09:56:37
09:46:47.659  D  2023.January.19 09:57:13
09:46:47.669  D  2023.January.19 09:57:35
09:46:47.671  D  2023.January.19 09:57:37
09:46:47.677  D  2023.January.19 10:01:37
09:46:47.685  D  2023.January.19 10:10:09
09:46:47.690  D  2023.January.19 10:10:23
09:46:47.695  D  2023.January.19 11:14:34
09:46:47.700  D  2023.January.19 11:17:46
09:46:47.706  D  2023.January.19 11:38:12
09:46:47.707  D  2023.January.19 11:40:36
09:46:47.712  D  2023.January.19 11:42:39
09:46:47.721  D  2023.January.19 11:42:40
09:46:47.725  D  2023.January.19 11:45:53
09:46:47.733  D  2023.January.19 11:50:02
09:46:47.745  D  2023.January.19 11:55:41
09:46:47.748  D  2023.January.19 11:58:49
09:46:47.755  D  2023.January.19 11:59:55
09:46:47.764  D  2023.January.19 12:11:48
09:46:47.767  D  2023.January.19 12:19:00
09:46:47.772  D  2023.January.19 14:39:22
09:46:47.774  D  2023.January.19 14:42:06
09:46:47.776  D  2023.January.19 14:45:27
09:46:47.785  D  2023.January.19 14:46:50
09:46:47.787  D  2023.January.19 14:53:06
09:46:47.788  D  2023.January.19 14:55:14
09:46:47.792  D  2023.January.19 14:56:15
09:46:47.797  D  2023.January.19 14:56:27
09:46:47.805  D  2023.January.19 14:58:24
09:46:47.809  D  2023.January.19 15:03:54
09:46:47.815  D  2023.January.19 15:20:43
09:46:47.818  D  2023.January.19 15:21:25
09:46:47.822  D  2023.January.19 15:25:14
09:46:47.833  D  2023.January.19 16:13:05
09:46:47.835  D  2023.January.19 16:14:33
09:46:47.837  D  2023.January.23 02:18:09
09:46:47.838  D  2023.January.23 02:18:20
09:46:47.839  D  2023.January.23 14:48:53
09:46:47.842  D  2023.January.23 15:08:18
09:46:47.852  D  2023.January.23 15:24:35
09:46:47.853  D  2023.January.23 16:35:08
09:46:47.855  D  2023.January.23 16:36:26
09:46:47.856  D  2023.January.23 17:26:10
09:46:47.865  D  2023.January.23 17:27:27
09:46:47.981  D  2023.January.23 17:30:12
09:46:47.982  D  2023.January.24 01:43:03
09:46:47.983  D  2023.January.24 01:57:53
09:46:47.985  D  2023.January.24 17:00:07
09:46:47.986  D  2023.January.24 17:03:23
09:46:47.991  D  2023.January.24 17:19:20
09:46:48.000  D  2023.January.24 17:26:35
09:46:48.001  D  2023.January.24 17:29:35
09:46:48.002  D  2023.January.24 19:11:49
09:46:48.003  D  2023.January.24 19:20:43
09:46:48.004  D  2023.January.24 19:30:47
09:46:48.005  D  2023.January.24 23:02:00
09:46:48.013  D  2023.January.24 23:51:33
```

Reopen the activity:

```
10:47:35.089  D  2023.January.18 16:51:53
10:47:35.090  D  2023.January.18 16:52:38
10:47:35.094  D  2023.January.18 17:03:41
10:47:35.095  D  2023.January.18 17:08:07
10:47:35.102  D  2023.January.18 17:08:31
10:47:35.114  D  2023.January.18 23:33:05
10:47:35.121  D  2023.January.18 23:36:35
10:47:35.147  D  2023.January.18 23:42:05
10:47:35.149  D  2023.January.18 23:50:51
10:47:35.150  D  2023.January.18 23:56:25
10:47:35.157  D  2023.January.19 00:04:04
10:47:35.163  D  2023.January.19 00:09:42
10:47:35.165  D  2023.January.19 00:12:10
10:47:35.177  D  2023.January.19 00:14:51
10:47:35.181  D  2023.January.19 00:18:51
10:47:35.198  D  2023.January.19 00:19:03
10:47:35.200  D  2023.January.19 00:20:57
10:47:35.211  D  2023.January.19 00:21:04
10:47:35.230  D  2023.January.19 01:33:20
10:47:35.240  D  2023.January.19 01:35:32
10:47:35.248  D  2023.January.19 01:39:22
10:47:35.278  D  2023.January.19 01:44:22
10:47:35.283  D  2023.January.19 01:44:44
10:47:35.313  D  2023.January.19 01:44:51
10:47:35.327  D  2023.January.19 01:47:24
10:47:35.330  D  2023.January.19 01:47:34
10:47:35.333  D  2023.January.19 01:47:57
10:47:35.339  D  2023.January.19 03:13:15
10:47:35.344  D  2023.January.19 03:22:25
10:47:35.347  D  2023.January.19 09:54:43
10:47:35.349  D  2023.January.19 09:56:37
10:47:35.351  D  2023.January.19 09:57:13
10:47:35.358  D  2023.January.19 09:57:35
10:47:35.364  D  2023.January.19 09:57:37
10:47:35.374  D  2023.January.19 10:01:37
10:47:35.387  D  2023.January.19 10:10:09
10:47:35.391  D  2023.January.19 10:10:23
10:47:35.418  D  2023.January.19 11:14:34
10:47:35.421  D  2023.January.19 11:17:46
10:47:35.428  D  2023.January.19 11:38:12
10:47:35.450  D  2023.January.19 11:40:36
10:47:35.466  D  2023.January.19 11:42:39
10:47:35.484  D  2023.January.19 11:42:40
10:47:35.493  D  2023.January.19 11:45:53
10:47:35.517  D  2023.January.19 11:50:02
10:47:35.532  D  2023.January.19 11:55:41
10:47:35.553  D  2023.January.19 11:58:49
10:47:35.582  D  2023.January.19 11:59:55
10:47:35.633  D  2023.January.19 12:11:48
10:47:35.649  D  2023.January.19 12:19:00
10:47:35.668  D  2023.January.19 14:39:22
10:47:35.679  D  2023.January.19 14:42:06
10:47:35.691  D  2023.January.19 14:45:27
10:47:35.751  D  2023.January.19 14:46:50
10:47:35.753  D  2023.January.19 14:53:06
10:47:35.763  D  2023.January.19 14:55:14
10:47:35.770  D  2023.January.19 14:56:15
10:47:35.775  D  2023.January.19 14:56:27
10:47:35.779  D  2023.January.19 14:58:24
10:47:35.781  D  2023.January.19 15:03:54
10:47:35.821  D  2023.January.19 15:20:43
10:47:35.831  D  2023.January.19 15:21:25
10:47:35.838  D  2023.January.19 15:25:14
10:47:35.852  D  2023.January.19 16:13:05
10:47:35.854  D  2023.January.19 16:14:33
10:47:35.871  D  2023.January.23 02:18:09
10:47:35.882  D  2023.January.23 02:18:20
10:47:35.884  D  2023.January.23 14:48:53
10:47:35.909  D  2023.January.23 15:08:18
10:47:35.916  D  2023.January.23 15:24:35
10:47:35.946  D  2023.January.23 16:35:08
10:47:35.952  D  2023.January.23 16:36:26
10:47:35.962  D  2023.January.23 17:26:10
10:47:35.965  D  2023.January.23 17:27:27
10:47:35.970  D  2023.January.23 17:30:12
10:47:35.993  D  2023.January.23 19:38:59
10:47:35.995  D  2023.January.23 19:39:26
10:47:36.000  D  2023.January.23 19:47:49
10:47:36.017  D  2023.January.23 19:55:49
10:47:36.021  D  2023.January.23 20:02:29
10:47:36.048  D  2023.January.23 20:03:04
10:47:36.052  D  2023.January.23 20:04:17
10:47:36.062  D  2023.January.23 20:10:48
10:47:36.081  D  2023.January.23 23:11:47
10:47:36.088  D  2023.January.23 23:16:48
10:47:36.094  D  2023.January.23 23:28:02
10:47:36.104  D  2023.January.24 00:39:23
10:47:36.136  D  2023.January.24 00:42:41
10:47:36.155  D  2023.January.24 00:44:08
10:47:36.162  D  2023.January.24 00:51:07
10:47:36.174  D  2023.January.24 00:53:10
10:47:36.175  D  2023.January.24 00:54:38
10:47:36.192  D  2023.January.24 00:56:56
10:47:36.221  D  2023.January.24 01:01:04
10:47:36.254  D  2023.January.24 01:04:54
10:47:36.274  D  2023.January.24 01:09:38
10:47:36.302  D  2023.January.24 01:11:18
10:47:36.312  D  2023.January.24 01:13:27
10:47:36.320  D  2023.January.24 01:19:44
10:47:36.344  D  2023.January.24 01:22:53
10:47:36.347  D  2023.January.24 01:23:18
10:47:36.351  D  2023.January.24 01:23:24
10:47:36.359  D  2023.January.24 01:28:55
10:47:36.362  D  2023.January.24 01:43:03
10:47:36.372  D  2023.January.24 01:57:53
10:47:36.374  D  2023.January.24 15:36:40
10:47:36.376  D  2023.January.24 15:39:37
10:47:36.389  D  2023.January.24 16:18:55
10:47:36.396  D  2023.January.24 16:20:22
10:47:36.507  D  2023.January.24 16:22:10
10:47:36.525  D  2023.January.24 16:56:45
10:47:36.541  D  2023.January.24 17:00:07
10:47:36.550  D  2023.January.24 17:00:32
10:47:36.560  D  2023.January.24 17:03:23
10:47:36.563  D  2023.January.24 17:03:37
10:47:36.610  D  2023.January.24 17:15:54
10:47:36.616  D  2023.January.24 17:16:01
10:47:36.623  D  2023.January.24 17:16:06
10:47:36.645  D  2023.January.24 17:19:20
10:47:36.648  D  2023.January.24 17:19:28
10:47:36.651  D  2023.January.24 17:19:33
10:47:36.685  D  2023.January.24 17:26:35
10:47:36.692  D  2023.January.24 17:26:45
10:47:36.694  D  2023.January.24 17:29:35
10:47:36.695  D  2023.January.24 17:29:41
10:47:36.698  D  2023.January.24 19:11:49
10:47:36.701  D  2023.January.24 19:12:07
10:47:36.740  D  2023.January.24 19:12:15
10:47:36.754  D  2023.January.24 19:20:43
10:47:36.757  D  2023.January.24 19:20:52
10:47:36.759  D  2023.January.24 19:20:58
10:47:36.761  D  2023.January.24 19:30:47
10:47:36.769  D  2023.January.24 19:30:58
10:47:36.773  D  2023.January.24 19:30:58
10:47:36.776  D  2023.January.24 19:31:02
10:47:36.778  D  2023.January.24 19:31:05
10:47:36.782  D  2023.January.24 19:41:30
10:47:36.790  D  2023.January.24 20:05:07
10:47:36.792  D  2023.January.24 23:02:00
10:47:36.796  D  2023.January.24 23:51:33
10:47:36.804  D  2023.January.24 23:51:42
```

Comment: I don't immediately see why the code you shared would get the documents in the wrong order. Can you update the code to log the offending `Date` value (instead of adding it to the UI), and then show us the updated code and its unexpected otput?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the question with new code and images of logs, on log part 2 things get out of order goes from 24 to 18 day. This only happens on a fresh installed app run. After that I have reopen page and the order was good.

Comment: Can you show the logs as text please? That allows you to more easily annotate where the problem in them occurs, makes them accessible to folks with visual impairments, makes them searchable, and allows them to copy/paste from them. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am sorry I edited.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the screenshot.

Comment: Seeing your DB schema, I can say that it looks good to me. The output is in ascending order, right? Isn't what you want?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I want that, but for that to happen the days in the output should be presented in the following order 18, 19, 23, 24 right? But what I get in the first app run is 19, 23, 24, 18, 19, 23, 24. Thats the confusing part. If I open the activity that is running that code again I obtain the right order, but  not at all on a fresh app run(adter install). I edited the question and added logs for the reopen of the activity to be possible to compare.